# Are there security risks to whitelisting all the column names in a model with strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm in the process of extracting some parts of a project into an engine and I wanted to whitelist user params in such a way that the user doesn't have to configure anything.

This is what I ultimately came up with:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(::User.columns.map(&:name), :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

It works so far (it allows all attributes in the user model and seems to reject anything else), however, I can't find another implementation of this in my searching that does it the same way and I'm wondering if that's because there's something I'm not seeing.

Is there a security vulnerability with setting strong params up like this?

Comment: After playing around a bit, I see that I can reset other fields (like id) if I PATCH from Postman which shouldn't be editable by the user so it seems like at least some fields should not be whitelisted.

Comment: Thats exactly how github got hacked and strong params where indroduced in the first place. https://gist.github.com/peternixey/1978249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a security vulnerability with setting strong params up like this?

Yes, there is. This defeats the purpose of *whitelisting*, which is to allow *some* fields, but not the others. Malicious clients will be able to write any of your fields, including, say, `roles` or `is_admin`.

If you don't have any restricted fields, you may skip strong params entirely and just use `params[:user]` (or `params` if your attributes are at the top level as shown in the question). The end result will be the same, but at least you won't have any illusions of security.

Comment: Is it fair to say it defeats the entire purpose? For example, a nefarious actor couldn't send anything they wanted to, only items in the user model (though you are correct, they could change things they shouldn't be able to like role or id). It would be possible to safeguard this case if I remove the sensitive items from the map though right? Then I can still get 0 config required from the user and a good whitelist?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone: see my comment about this in the other answer. Nefarious actors sending non-existing fields will result in an exception at worst. No security risk here.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone: if you want to prevent those exceptions, then fair enough, it's a valid approach.

Comment: Going to accept this one as the answer, thanks for helping me look at this correctly.

Comment: Another key point is that strong params is a controller concern not a model concern. Before the Homakov github attack model based parameter vetting was all the rage. But this approach has been proven to be very flawed since models are not request aware and the permissable parameters depend on the request context.

Comment: I also think that using `params[:user]` directly will give a `ForbiddenAttributesError` as rails will actually try to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. The params hash is not actually a Hash but rather a hash like object that has a flag which marks it as insecure.

Comment: This is true for Rails 4+.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm in the process of extracting some parts of a project into an
>   engine and I wanted to whitelist user params in such a way that the
>   user doesn't have to configure anything.

*The road the hell is paved with good intentions.* What you are actually doing is just creating a [mass assigment vulnerablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) for any users of your gem.

> Is there a security vulnerability with setting strong params up like
>   this?

Yes. A malicous user can assign the `id` param or `admin = true` for example. Thats the exact scenario strong parameters is meant to avoid.

You should also wrap your head around that parameter whitelisting is not a model concern. That approach has been deemed deeply flawed since models are not request aware and the parameters that should be permitted can depend on the context and authorization.

### Don't be that guy.

As a gem author your responsibility is to be secure by default. Convention over configuration means providing a good set of defaults - not making it idiot friendly.

You might want to look at Devise and provide a set of good default parameters and allow users to override it.

```
class SomeGem::UserController < SomeGem::BaseController

  def create
    @user = User.new(create_params)
    if @user.save
      yield @user if block_given?
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  private 

  def create_params
    params.require(param_key).permit(*base_params)
  end

  def base_params
    :email, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation
  end

  def param_key
     :user
  end
end
```

This can then be simply overridden by users of the gem:

```
class MyUserController < SomeGem::UserController
  private

  def base_params
    super + [:first_name, :last_name]
  end
end
```

An alternative to inheritance is by using a [config option](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block) which can be changed in an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers).

Comment: Thanks Max, that's good info as always :) and a good mindset. I ended up going with the config option, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `permit!` method. See [Rails API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21)

> This can be used to pass mass assignment

Comment: I don't want to permit all fields, just the ones defined in the user model

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone: why? If a client tries to set a non-existing field, you'll get an exception, that's all.

Comment: Yep, I see I mis-read the doc. I thought permit! was like turning off strong params to accept anything. Maybe I should have asked the question differently (e.g. how can I get the benefit of strong params with 0 user config for an engine)

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone: I'm afraid you can't. If your engine is meant to be generic, then it'll be used in wildly different apps, where users have different sets of fields with varying levels of protection. There's no way you can foresee which of those user does _not_ want to be mass-assigned through the UI. If it's your internal engine, where you controll all the future apps it'll be used in, then you're free to do whatever, and it will work.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone: the benefit of strong params is to not restrict all possible input to only those columns actually existing. it is to filter it further and reject some of the existing columns too. Which ones? You can't know without user doing some configuration.

Comment: It's a fair point. I was thinking too narrowly in terms of what works in the test apps and not from a wide enough perspective of what more users might want to do. Thank you for the input!